# How to install Eclipse Neon behind a proxy

Tags: java, eclipse

With Neon, Eclipse comes with an installer.
I could not find any configuration menu in the installer.
My java version is:

```
java -version
java version "1.8.0_72"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_72-b15)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 25.72-b15, mixed mode)
```

on an ubuntu 14.04 64 bits.

I tried to configure the proxy in the eclipse-inst.ini:

```
...
-Djava.net.useSystemProxies=true
-Dhttps.proxyPort=8888
-Dhttp.proxyPort=8888
-Dhttps.proxyHost=localproxy
-Dhttp.proxyHost=localproxy
```

as documented here https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/net/proxies.html
but the installer hangs...

Comment: From the download page, there's link to directly download packages (regular zip or tar.gz files) that you can use an an alternative to the installer.

Answer (score 16):

There are two options:

1. Download a full package instead of using the installer. There's a link right on the downloads page, but [here's where to get the packages](https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/eclipse-packages/).
2. Switch the installer to Advanced Mode (use the menu button in the top-right corner of the installer window). In Advanced Mode there is a place to confiure proxy settings:

[image]

Comment: Very nice! I missed both  the dull grey "download packages" just below the flashy orange  "download 64 bit"on the eclipse download page, and the tiny icon in a rich advanced mode screen! You answer will surely be useful!

Answer (score 2):

A simpler approach would be to set up proxy in your command line:

Linux:

```
bash $ export http_proxy=http://www-proxy.example.com:80
bash $ export https_proxy=http://www-proxy.example.com:80 # Replace with your proxy protocol, url and port.
bash $ cd <Folder where Eclipse installer is downloaded>
bash $ ./eclipse-inst

csh $ setenv http_proxy http://user:password@proxy.domain.com:port
csh $ setenv https_proxy http://user:password@proxy.domain.com:port
csh $ cd <Folder where Eclipse installer is downloaded>
csh $ ./eclipse-inst
```

Windows:

```
set HTTP_PROXY=http://user:password@proxy.domain.com:port
set HTTPS_PROXY=http://user:password@proxy.domain.com:port
```

and invoke the eclipse-inst tool from the same command line.

Answer (score 0):

I could find a workaround, which is to copy a valid network configuration from a previous Eclipse Mars configuration.

`cp <old_eclipse>/configuration/.settings/org.eclipse.core.net.prefs <neon_installer_path>/eclipse-installer/configuration/.settings`

It works, but it really looks like a hack, any other clues?

Answer (score 0):

Solution worked for me:
Windows:

set HTTP_PROXY=http://user:password@proxy.domain.com:port
set HTTPS_PROXY=http://user:password@proxy.domain.com:port
and invoke the eclipse-inst tool from the same command line.