# Installation error Eclipse: Installation Failed

Tags: java, eclipse, installation, windows-10

I downloaded eclipse installer, but am unable to install it(Windows 10 64 bit).
Here's the installation log.
I tried running the installer as administrator, but it did not solve the problem.
Eclipse Download link - https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/download.php?file=/oomph/products/eclipse-inst-win64.exe
I have been trying to solve this issue from 2 days but nothing has worked.

````
[2021-03-08 15:50:30] OpenJDK Runtime Environment 15.0.1+9-18
[2021-03-08 15:50:30] Product org.eclipse.products.epp.package.java.2020-12
[2021-03-08 15:50:30] Bundle org.eclipse.oomph.setup 1.18.0.v20200820-0414, build=4919, branch=f78238ba11ce04fb6bb89f0cb98f4dd759377d1d
[2021-03-08 15:50:30] Bundle org.eclipse.oomph.setup.core 1.18.0.v20200624-1156, build=4919, branch=f78238ba11ce04fb6bb89f0cb98f4dd759377d1d
[2021-03-08 15:50:30] Bundle org.eclipse.oomph.setup.p2 1.16.0.v20200814-1205, build=4919, branch=f78238ba11ce04fb6bb89f0cb98f4dd759377d1d
[2021-03-08 15:50:30] Performing P2 Director (Eclipse IDE for Java Developers (2020-12) + JRE 15.0.2)
[2021-03-08 15:50:30] Offline = false
[2021-03-08 15:50:31] Mirrors = true
[2021-03-08 15:50:31] Resolving 18 requirements from 4 repositoriesto C:\Users\hp\eclipse\java-2020-12\eclipse
[2021-03-08 15:50:31] Requirement org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu:org.eclipse.justj.openjdk.hotspot.jre.full.feature.group (filter=(|(&(osgi.arch=x86_64)(osgi.os=linux))(&(osgi.arch=aarch64)(osgi.os=linux))(&(osgi.arch=x86_64)(osgi.os=macosx))(&(osgi.arch=x86_64)(osgi.os=win32))))
[2021-03-08 15:50:31] Requirement org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu:epp.package.java [4.18.0,5.0.0)
[2021-03-08 15:50:31] Requirement org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu:org.eclipse.platform.feature.group [4.18.0,5.0.0)
[2021-03-08 15:50:31] Requirement org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu:org.eclipse.rcp.feature.group [4.18.0,5.0.0)
[2021-03-08 15:50:31] Requirement org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu:org.eclipse.buildship.feature.group
[2021-03-08 15:50:31] Requirement org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu:org.eclipse.eclemma.feature.feature.group
[2021-03-08 15:50:31] Requirement org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu:org.eclipse.egit.feature.group
[2021-03-08 15:50:31] Requirement org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu:org.eclipse.epp.mpc.feature.group
[2021-03-08 15:50:31] Requirement org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu:org.eclipse.jdt.feature.group
[2021-03-08 15:50:31] Requirement org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu:org.eclipse.jgit.feature.group
[2021-03-08 15:50:31] Requirement org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu:org.eclipse.m2e.feature.feature.group
[2021-03-08 15:50:31] Requirement org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu:org.eclipse.m2e.lemminx.feature.feature.group
[2021-03-08 15:50:31] Requirement org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu:org.eclipse.m2e.logback.feature.feature.group
[2021-03-08 15:50:31] Requirement org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu:org.eclipse.mylyn.wikitext.editors_feature.feature.group
[2021-03-08 15:50:31] Requirement org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu:org.eclipse.tips.feature.feature.group
[2021-03-08 15:50:31] Requirement org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu:org.eclipse.tm.terminal.feature.feature.group
[2021-03-08 15:50:31] Requirement org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu:org.eclipse.wildwebdeveloper.xml.feature.feature.group
[2021-03-08 15:50:31] Requirement org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu:org.eclipse.oomph.setup.feature.group
[2021-03-08 15:50:31] Repository http://download.eclipse.org/justj/jres/15/updates/release/15.0.2
[2021-03-08 15:50:31] Repository http://download.eclipse.org/technology/epp/packages/2020-12/202012101200
[2021-03-08 15:50:31] Repository http://download.eclipse.org/releases/2020-12/202012161000
[2021-03-08 15:50:31] Repository http://download.eclipse.org/oomph/updates/milestone/latest
[2021-03-08 15:50:32] ERROR: org.eclipse.equinox.p2.transport.ecf code=1002 Unable to read repository at http://download.eclipse.org/releases/2020-12/202012161000/content.xml.
java.net.SocketException: Address family not supported by protocol family: connect
  at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.connect0(Native Method)
  at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.connect(Unknown Source)
  at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.connect(Unknown Source)
  at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
  at java.base/java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
  at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
  at org.apache.http.conn.socket.PlainConnectionSocketFactory.connectSocket(PlainConnectionSocketFactory.java:75)
  at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.java:142)
  at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.connect(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:374)
  at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.establishRoute(MainClientExec.java:393)
  at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:236)
  at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:186)
  at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:89)
  at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:110)
  at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:185)
  at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:83)
  at org.eclipse.ecf.provider.filetransfer.httpclient45.HttpClientFileSystemBrowser.runRequest(HttpClientFileSystemBrowser.java:248)
  at org.eclipse.ecf.provider.filetransfer.browse.AbstractFileSystemBrowser$DirectoryJob.run(AbstractFileSystemBrowser.java:71)
  at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:63)

[2021-03-08 15:50:32] 
[2021-03-08 15:50:57] Executing bootstrap tasks
[2021-03-08 15:50:57] OpenJDK Runtime Environment 15.0.1+9-18
[2021-03-08 15:50:57] Product org.eclipse.products.epp.package.java.2020-12
[2021-03-08 15:50:57] Bundle org.eclipse.oomph.setup 1.18.0.v20200820-0414, build=4919, branch=f78238ba11ce04fb6bb89f0cb98f4dd759377d1d
[2021-03-08 15:50:57] Bundle org.eclipse.oomph.setup.core 1.18.0.v20200624-1156, build=4919, branch=f78238ba11ce04fb6bb89f0cb98f4dd759377d1d
[2021-03-08 15:50:57] Bundle org.eclipse.oomph.setup.p2 1.16.0.v20200814-1205, build=4919, branch=f78238ba11ce04fb6bb89f0cb98f4dd759377d1d
[2021-03-08 15:50:57] Performing P2 Director (Eclipse IDE for Java Developers (2020-12) + JRE 15.0.2)
[2021-03-08 15:50:57] Offline = false
[2021-03-08 15:50:57] Mirrors = true
[2021-03-08 15:50:57] Resolving 18 requirements from 4 repositoriesto C:\Users\hp\eclipse\java-2020-12\eclipse
[2021-03-08 15:50:57] Requirement org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu:org.eclipse.justj.openjdk.hotspot.jre.full.feature.group (filter=(|(&(osgi.arch=x86_64)(osgi.os=linux))(&(osgi.arch=aarch64)(osgi.os=linux))(&(osgi.arch=x86_64)(osgi.os=macosx))(&(osgi.arch=x86_64)(osgi.os=win32))))
[2021-03-08 15:50:57] Requirement org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu:epp.package.java [4.18.0,5.0.0)
[2021-03-08 15:50:57] Requirement org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu:org.eclipse.platform.feature.group [4.18.0,5.0.0)
[2021-03-08 15:50:57] Requirement org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu:org.eclipse.rcp.feature.group [4.18.0,5.0.0)
[2021-03-08 15:50:57] Requirement org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu:org.eclipse.buildship.feature.group
[2021-03-08 15:50:57] Requirement org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu:org.eclipse.eclemma.feature.feature.group
[2021-03-08 15:50:57] Requirement org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu:org.eclipse.egit.feature.group
[2021-03-08 15:50:57] Requirement org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu:org.eclipse.epp.mpc.feature.group
[2021-03-08 15:50:57] Requirement org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu:org.eclipse.jdt.feature.group
[2021-03-08 15:50:57] Requirement org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu:org.eclipse.jgit.feature.group
[2021-03-08 15:50:57] Requirement org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu:org.eclipse.m2e.feature.feature.group
[2021-03-08 15:50:57] Requirement org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu:org.eclipse.m2e.lemminx.feature.feature.group
[2021-03-08 15:50:57] Requirement org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu:org.eclipse.m2e.logback.feature.feature.group
[2021-03-08 15:50:57] Requirement org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu:org.eclipse.mylyn.wikitext.editors_feature.feature.group
[2021-03-08 15:50:57] Requirement org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu:org.eclipse.tips.feature.feature.group
[2021-03-08 15:50:57] Requirement org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu:org.eclipse.tm.terminal.feature.feature.group
[2021-03-08 15:50:57] Requirement org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu:org.eclipse.wildwebdeveloper.xml.feature.feature.group
[2021-03-08 15:50:57] Requirement org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu:org.eclipse.oomph.setup.feature.group
[2021-03-08 15:50:57] Repository http://download.eclipse.org/justj/jres/15/updates/release/15.0.2
[2021-03-08 15:50:57] Repository http://download.eclipse.org/technology/epp/packages/2020-12/202012101200
[2021-03-08 15:50:57] Repository http://download.eclipse.org/releases/2020-12/202012161000
[2021-03-08 15:50:57] Repository http://download.eclipse.org/oomph/updates/milestone/latest
[2021-03-08 15:50:58] ERROR: org.eclipse.equinox.p2.transport.ecf code=1002 Unable to read repository at http://download.eclipse.org/justj/jres/15/updates/release/15.0.2/content.xml.
java.net.SocketException: Address family not supported by protocol family: connect
  at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.connect0(Native Method)
  at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.connect(Unknown Source)
  at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.connect(Unknown Source)
  at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
  at java.base/java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
  at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
  at org.apache.http.conn.socket.PlainConnectionSocketFactory.connectSocket(PlainConnectionSocketFactory.java:75)
  at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.java:142)
  at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.connect(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:374)
  at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.establishRoute(MainClientExec.java:393)
  at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:236)
  at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:186)
  at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:89)
  at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:110)
  at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:185)
  at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:83)
  at org.eclipse.ecf.provider.filetransfer.httpclient45.HttpClientFileSystemBrowser.runRequest(HttpClientFileSystemBrowser.java:248)
  at org.eclipse.ecf.provider.filetransfer.browse.AbstractFileSystemBrowser$DirectoryJob.run(AbstractFileSystemBrowser.java:71)
  at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:63)

[2021-03-08 15:50:58] 
[2021-03-08 15:55:25] Executing bootstrap tasks
[2021-03-08 15:55:25] OpenJDK Runtime Environment 15.0.1+9-18
[2021-03-08 15:55:25] Product org.eclipse.products.epp.package.java.2020-12
[2021-03-08 15:55:25] Bundle org.eclipse.oomph.setup 1.18.0.v20200820-0414, build=4919, branch=f78238ba11ce04fb6bb89f0cb98f4dd759377d1d
[2021-03-08 15:55:25] Bundle org.eclipse.oomph.setup.core 1.18.0.v20200624-1156, build=4919, branch=f78238ba11ce04fb6bb89f0cb98f4dd759377d1d
[2021-03-08 15:55:25] Bundle org.eclipse.oomph.setup.p2 1.16.0.v20200814-1205, build=4919, branch=f78238ba11ce04fb6bb89f0cb98f4dd759377d1d
[2021-03-08 15:55:25] Performing P2 Director (Eclipse IDE for Java Developers (2020-12) + JRE 14.0.2)
[2021-03-08 15:55:25] Offline = false
[2021-03-08 15:55:25] Mirrors = true
[2021-03-08 15:55:25] Resolving 18 requirements from 4 repositoriesto C:\Users\hp\eclipse\java-2020-12\eclipse
[2021-03-08 15:55:25] Requirement org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu:org.eclipse.justj.openjdk.hotspot.jre.full.feature.group (filter=(|(&(osgi.arch=x86_64)(osgi.os=linux))(&(osgi.arch=x86_64)(osgi.os=macosx))(&(osgi.arch=x86_64)(osgi.os=win32))))
[2021-03-08 15:55:25] Requirement org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu:epp.package.java [4.18.0,5.0.0)
[2021-03-08 15:55:25] Requirement org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu:org.eclipse.platform.feature.group [4.18.0,5.0.0)
[2021-03-08 15:55:25] Requirement org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu:org.eclipse.rcp.feature.group [4.18.0,5.0.0)
[2021-03-08 15:55:25] Requirement org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu:org.eclipse.buildship.feature.group
[2021-03-08 15:55:25] Requirement org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu:org.eclipse.eclemma.feature.feature.group
[2021-03-08 15:55:25] Requirement org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu:org.eclipse.egit.feature.group
[2021-03-08 15:55:25] Requirement org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu:org.eclipse.epp.mpc.feature.group
[2021-03-08 15:55:25] Requirement org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu:org.eclipse.jdt.feature.group
[2021-03-08 15:55:25] Requirement org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu:org.eclipse.jgit.feature.group
[2021-03-08 15:55:25] Requirement org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu:org.eclipse.m2e.feature.feature.group
[2021-03-08 15:55:25] Requirement org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu:org.eclipse.m2e.lemminx.feature.feature.group
[2021-03-08 15:55:25] Requirement org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu:org.eclipse.m2e.logback.feature.feature.group
[2021-03-08 15:55:25] Requirement org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu:org.eclipse.mylyn.wikitext.editors_feature.feature.group
[2021-03-08 15:55:25] Requirement org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu:org.eclipse.tips.feature.feature.group
[2021-03-08 15:55:25] Requirement org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu:org.eclipse.tm.terminal.feature.feature.group
[2021-03-08 15:55:25] Requirement org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu:org.eclipse.wildwebdeveloper.xml.feature.feature.group
[2021-03-08 15:55:25] Requirement org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu:org.eclipse.oomph.setup.feature.group
[2021-03-08 15:55:25] Repository http://download.eclipse.org/justj/jres/14/updates/release/14.0.2
[2021-03-08 15:55:25] Repository http://download.eclipse.org/technology/epp/packages/2020-12/202012101200
[2021-03-08 15:55:25] Repository http://download.eclipse.org/releases/2020-12/202012161000
[2021-03-08 15:55:25] Repository http://download.eclipse.org/oomph/updates/milestone/latest
[2021-03-08 15:55:26] ERROR: org.eclipse.equinox.p2.transport.ecf code=1002 Unable to read repository at http://download.eclipse.org/oomph/updates/milestone/latest/content.xml.
java.net.SocketException: Address family not supported by protocol family: connect
  at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.connect0(Native Method)
  at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.connect(Unknown Source)
  at java.base/sun.nio.ch.Net.connect(Unknown Source)
  at java.base/sun.nio.ch.NioSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
  at java.base/java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)
  at java.base/java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)
  at org.apache.http.conn.socket.PlainConnectionSocketFactory.connectSocket(PlainConnectionSocketFactory.java:75)
  at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.connect(DefaultHttpClientConnectionOperator.java:142)
  at org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.connect(PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager.java:374)
  at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.establishRoute(MainClientExec.java:393)
  at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec.execute(MainClientExec.java:236)
  at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.ProtocolExec.execute(ProtocolExec.java:186)
  at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RetryExec.execute(RetryExec.java:89)
  at org.apache.http.impl.execchain.RedirectExec.execute(RedirectExec.java:110)
  at org.apache.http.impl.client.InternalHttpClient.doExecute(InternalHttpClient.java:185)
  at org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient.execute(CloseableHttpClient.java:83)
  at org.eclipse.ecf.provider.filetransfer.httpclient45.HttpClientFileSystemBrowser.runRequest(HttpClientFileSystemBrowser.java:248)
  at org.eclipse.ecf.provider.filetransfer.browse.AbstractFileSystemBrowser$DirectoryJob.run(AbstractFileSystemBrowser.java:71)
  at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:63)```

[2021-03-08 15:55:26]
````

Comment: Running the Eclipse Installer as administrator is a bad idea if you do not want run Eclipse also as administrator from now on. Are you behind a proxy? You can download an IDE package directly: https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/ (the Eclipse Installer saves disk space when having more than one Eclipse IDE installed).

Comment: Seems to be a network / proxy issue. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39169025/how-to-install-eclipse-neon-behind-a-proxy